# Will my SO question be appropriate on ServerFault?

Tags: discussion, questions, stackoverflow

Could you please let me know if [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810835/error-connecting-stand-alone-java-program-to-jms-on-wildfly-server), currently posted on Stack Overflow, is acceptable for Server Fault.  The problem is that a program cannot communicate with WildFly server.

The same program was reported to work OK on multiple other machines.

So something either wrong with the program (which is unlikely but possible) or the server configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With only 6 questions that mention it we're not exactly a hot bed of [wildfly](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wildfly) knowledge so I'd say no, you're better off leaving it where it is where there is a [larger body of knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WildFly).

It also looks to my unknowledgeable eye pretty much like any other java error dump and therefore a case of rolling up your sleeves and debugging it.

Comment: I've run it under debugger several times and know exactly *where* it breaks, know the values used, etc. I still can't find out *why*. So I need ideas where to look.

Comment: It looks like you're also doing this on your development workstation - you should take a look at our [about] as it explicitly puts development environments like this out of scope for SF.

Comment: OK. So it stays on SO.